# Customizing QCompleter

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qcompleter

I'm making a window that has a search(used QLineEdit). In every key pressing, there should be a completer for displaying results as a table. I want to use QCompleter but it only shows results just like a QComboBox. Now I'm going to customize QCompleter. It seems hard to me. What could you suggest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set widget to completer using `QCompleter::setPopup()`. see [completer example](https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/examples/widgets/tools/completer/mainwindow.cpp#n270)

Comment: thank you, you saved me from working a lot! giving QTableWidget to setPopup method and `QCompleter::setModel(myTable->model());` were enough.